# Proguard does not remove certain classes

Tags: scala, proguard

All

I am using proguard to obfuscate a scala application.

At this point I am using very little of the scala-library, but still my jar is ~300KB, 99% of it are scala-library classes.

Using the -whyareyoukeeping option, I see that it keeps any class that overrides java.lang.Object methods, such as "toString" or "equals".
For example

```
scala.Some
  is invoked by    scala.Some.equals (300:300)
  implements       java.lang.Object.equals
  is a library method.
```

And so scala.Some class is kept although I am not using it in my code.

Is there anyway to fix this, so that I only keep the classes I am actually using in my code?

Thanks
Amir

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard's answer to `-whyareyoukeeping` sometimes contains a circular reasoning, unfortunately. The shrinking operation is correct though. The class is not preserved because it overrides *equals()*, but because it is actually referenced by some other class that is required. You may get a better impression by querying other classes.

Even a small piece of Scala can drag in a lot of basic classes due to transitive dependencies (often surprising at first sight). A final size of 300k doesn't seem out of the ordinary, compared to the original size of many megabytes.